# Changing color of background of tkinter window by using colorchooser in python 3 and tkinter

Tags: python, colors, background, window, tkinter

How can I change color of tkinter window(background) in python 3, by using colorchooser?

for now I made this:

```
from tkinter import colorchooser

def color1():
    color = colorchooser.askcolor()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a window named root, to change the background color using colorchooser, you would do:

```
color = colorchooser.askcolor()
color_name = color[1]    #to pick up the color name in HTML notation, i.e. the 2nd element of the tuple returned by the colorchooser
root.configure(background=color_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the root window is name `root`, you would do:

```
root.configure(background=color)
```

Comment: How can I make that color changed in all windows, not just in main window, I tried some options but they didn't work?

Comment: @TheQuiteStupidMan: you have to call the `configure` method of every window you want to change.

Answer (score 0):

Bryan Oakley code is correct

```
root.configure(background="color")
```

but, `color` must be enclosed with quotes single(`''`) or double(`""`)